# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on Quick Sort?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, quicksort

I'm getting a segmentation fault from running a quicksort algorithm.
Here is my code

Sortings.h

```
    class Sortings {
     public:
      static void QuickSort(int* array, int size);
     private:
      static int partition(int* array, int l, int r);
      static void Quicksort_helper(int* array, int l, int r);
    };
```

Sortings.cpp

```
#include "Sortings.h"
void Sortings::QuickSort(int* array, int size){
  Quicksort_helper(array, 0, size);
}

int Sortings::partition(int* array, int l, int r){
  int p = array[l];
  int i = l;
  int j = r + 1;
  while (!(i <= j)){
    while (!(array[i] >= p))
      i = i+1;
    while (!(array[j] <=  p))
      j = j-1;
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  int temp2 = array[i];
  array[i] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp2;
  int temp3 = array[l];
  array[l] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp3;
  return j;
}

void Sortings::Quicksort_helper(int* array, int l, int r){
  if (l < r){
    int s = partition(array, l, r);
    Quicksort_helper(array, l, (s-1));
    Quicksort_helper(array, (s+1), r);
  }
}
```

In main.cpp I call Quicksort with an input array and size variable.
Why is there a Segmentation fault when I run my main.cpp?

Comment: Apparently `array out of bounds`.

Comment: Although some of StackOverflow members like to work as mental compilers and debuggers, next time consider to use debugger of your favorite C++ IDE, it will give you an answer faster, you will learn much more, and most important you will learn to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the size in as r.  You set j=r+1.  You loop for i=l to j.  That's going out of bounds of your array.  The valid bounds are [0,r-1].  You're looping until r+1.  That's your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The size is passed on to r and then there is indexing #

```
 int j = r + 1;
 ...
 while (!(array[j] <=  p))
     j = j-1;
```

If size really is "size", then you are out of the array.

Maybe:

```
Quicksort_helper(array, 0, size - 1);
```